# Python3 pip3 command not found after installing package (Centos 7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, centos

I’ve just deployed a VM on microsoft azure, a Centos 7(B1s)

Right now I am trying to install python3 and pip3. I followed this [tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/install-python-pip-centos7/) to install them. Then I checked the packages installed in yum by the following:

`sudo yum list installed`

as you can see, python3 and pip3 should already be here

```
python-urllib3.noarch                  1.10.2-7.el7                   @os       
python2-futures.noarch                 3.1.1-5.el7                    @os       
python2-pyasn1.noarch                  0.1.9-7.el7                    @os       
python34.x86_64                        3.4.10-7.el7                   @epel     
python34-libs.x86_64                   3.4.10-7.el7                   @epel     
python34-pip.noarch                    8.1.2-14.el7                   @epel     
python34-setuptools.noarch             39.2.0-4.el7                   @epel     
pyxattr.x86_64                         0.5.1-5.el7                    @os       
qrencode-libs.x86_64                   3.4.1-3.el7                    @os       
…
```

And I did

```
rpm -ql python34.x86_64

/usr/bin/pydoc3.4
/usr/bin/python3.4
…

rpm -ql python34-pip.noarch

/usr/bin/pip3.4
/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip
…
/usr/share/doc/python34-pip-8.1.2
…
```

**So I believe they should’ve been installed.** But then I still run into the error:

```
python3
-bash: python3: command not found
pip
-bash: pip: command not found
```

And same for pip3.

**What I tried**

I think there might be something wrong with the path variable, so I echoed the path

```
echo $PATH

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/azure/.local/bin:/home/azure/bin:
```

That’s where I thought I found the source of error: the /usr/lib/ and  /usr/share/ are not included.
Then I edited ~/.bash_profile by adding the following at the end:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/share"
```

and then

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

But the problem still persists.

I am out of idea now. Previously I’ve run into this kind of issue several times, but I don’t recall something I can’t fix with changing $PATH or using conda. Right now my situation is a bit awkward as I don’t want to install conda on this machine(there’s not much space here, I can’t afford much…) and I really want to know what exactly went wrong.

Any help or hint would be appreciated ;)

Comment: The 3 year old "tutorial" is about pip34, python34 . Today python3 is in the CentOS7 Base repo http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/ → python3-3.6.8-17.el7, python3-pip-9.0.3-8.el7 (pip3).

Comment: Dear @KnudLarsen, thanks for the info. I have checked the /bin/ of the VM and it has python 3.4 with it. Besides the issue still persist. I tried to look for the path for python3 by `which python3` but the outcome is just `/usr/bin/which: no python3 in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/azure/.local/bin:/home/azure/bin:/usr/lib:/usr/share)`
I attempted to use rpm to install the python3.6 rpm file as well(I know I probably shouldn't, but can't think of other way to bypass the issue), that failed as well.

Comment: Why not use `yum install python3-devel python3-pip` ? ?

Comment: Dear @KnudLarsen: it worked well, thank you very much! Please add a comment below so I could accept answer, and make it easier for others to read :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CentOS 7**

The 3 year old "tutorial" https://linuxhint.com/install-python-pip-centos7/  is about pip34, python34 .

Today python3 is in the CentOS 7 Base repo  http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/
→ `python3-3.6.8-17.el7`, `python3-pip-9.0.3-8.el7` (pip3)

Install python3 :

```
# yum install python3-devel python3-pip
```

---