# Python3 module not found error after installation with pip3

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, pip, centos

I have been stuck on a module not found error of python3.
I have a VM on Microsoft Azure, a Centos 7. Then I installed python3 and pip3, and some packages I needed. But there’s one package that I just couldn’t find after I installed it

`sudo pip3 install --user stockstats`

But whenever i wanted to run a python script using this package, there’s
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stockstats'`

**What I tried:**

`pip3 show stockstats`

As I really want to see where it was installed. It shows nothing. What it is supposed to do is like this:

```
Name: openpyxl
Version: 3.0.7
Summary: A Python library to read/write Excel 2010 xlsx/xlsm files
Home-page: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io
Author: See AUTHORS
Author-email: charlie.clark@clark-consulting.eu
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
…
```

Then I guess it might be something wrong with the installed path, so I uninstalled the package, and then did

```
sudo pip3 install stockstats --install-option="--prefix=/usr/local/lib"
```

(I am just guessing if openpyxl is installed there then stockstats should be there too, as python imported openpyxl successfully)
That didn’t work as well, the error still persists.

*I didn’t use any package manager other than pip3.

** some irregularities occurred when I was trying to use python3([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67898062/python3-pip3-command-not-found-after-installing-package-centos-7)). It was resolved, but I am not sure if the error in this post is related to that.

Any help or hint would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Maybe it's a mixup of which version of Python you're using for installing versus running? However you're running python scripts (e.g. `python3 ~/whatever.py`), try using the pip associated with that python version: instead of `pip3 install ...`, use `python3 -m pip install ...`. That's one possibility anyway.

Comment: `sudo pip3 install --user stockstats` runs under user `root` and hence installs the package into `/root/.local/lib/` so the package is only available for scripts running under `root`. Did you run `pip3 show stockstats` under the same user `root` or a different user? For a different user you have to install it under the same user or better install it globally: `sudo pip3 install stockstats` (without `--user`). Also verify that `sudo pip3 --version` and `pip3 --version` runs under the same python.

Comment: You [do not *ever* run `pip` as root](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/do-not-run-pip-as-root). Unless it's in a virtual environment (`virtualenv`). *ONLY* then it's fine to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the prompt reply.
After Guo Lei’s comment, I tried downloading the tar ball for this package and installing it myself without pip, which eventually told me what exactly happened: a module named int-date, required by stockstats, was not installed in the python library directory. After I installed it in the proper directory, the issue is resolved.

As Danila Vershinin and phd had pointed out, I really shouldn’t run pip as root, and that is the source of issue(curiously, however, that only one particular module required by stockstats is installed in /root/.local/lib/. All others are in the right place, maybe I added the prefix flag without remembering it...?)

Still, I am not sure, I ran pip using sudo because I received permission denied errors repeatedly — so should I use something like sudo --user? Or sth else?

Answer (score -2):

- You can visit This website for Installing pip in centos 7 [Pip Install In Centos 7](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-pip-on-centos-7/)

for maybe some errors in installing pip.

- reinstall python.
- check that the module name is correctly typed
- install stockstats in pip like "pip install stockstats" (getten from pypi.com)

Answer (score -2):

This works for me.

```
pip install -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple stockstats
```

or

```
pip config set global.index-url https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
pip install stockstats
```